# Eigenvalues of a diagonal minus rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given

$$\lambda \left( Daa^TD \right)  = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{with multiplicity}~ d-1 \\ 1 & \text{with multiplicity}~1 \end{cases}$$

is it possible to compute $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ of $D-Daa^TD$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $D_{ii}\geq 0$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$ column vector.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information we have about $M = Daa^TD$ is that $M$ is a rank-$1$ positive definite symmetric matrix with trace $1$ whose image lies inside the image of $D$.  This is not enough to say much at all about the eigenvalues of $D-Daa^TD$.

Let $d_{\max},d_{\min}$ denote the maximum and minimum diagonal entries of $D$. Using [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) (or a similar, weaker result), we can show that 
$$
d_{\max} - 1 \leq \lambda_{\max} \leq d_{\max}, \qquad 
d_{\min} - 1 \leq \lambda_{\min} \leq d_{\min} .
$$
These inequalities are strict, and it is possible to find a vector $a$ that produces any desired $\lambda_{\max}$ (or $\lambda_{\min}$) within the interval defined above.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, may I ask if $||a||=1$ is imposed will affect the inequalities and make them less generic?

Comment: I missed a detail, see my latest edit. We can improve the bounds a bit

Comment: Regarding you comment: If you only impose $\|a\| = 1$ then that's pretty much the same situation. If you impose both $\|a\| = 1$ and the non-zero eigenvalue of $Daa^TD$, then that might give you a bit more.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback, shouldn't we have $d_{\min}-1\leq \lambda_{min} \leq d_{min}$?

Comment: Yes silly mistake

Comment: Thanks again for the interest!